# Convert date from "yyyy/mm/dd" format to "M/d/yyyy" format in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am reading a table to a dataframe which has a column "day_dt" which is in date format "2022/01/08". I want the format to be in "1/8/2022" (M/d/yyyy) Is it possible in pyspark? I have tried using date_format() but resulting in null.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have tried and also the sample data

Answer (score 0):

Did you cast day_dt column to timestamp before using date_format? Code below adds a null valued column as you described in your question because it is StringType. You can see it using df.printSchema()

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

d = ['2022/01/08']
df = spark.createDataFrame(d, StringType())
df.show()

df2 = df.withColumn("newDate", date_format(unix_timestamp(df.value , 
"yyyy/mm/dd").cast("timestamp"),"mm/dd/yyyy"))
df2.show()

+----------+
|     value|
+----------+
|2022/01/08|
+----------+

+----------+-------+
|     value|newDate|
+----------+-------+
|2022/01/08|   null|
+----------+-------+
```

After casting string type to timestamp, date column is formatted properly:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

d = ['2022/01/08']
df = spark.createDataFrame(d, StringType())
df.show()

df2 = df.withColumn("newDate", date_format(unix_timestamp(df.value , "yyyy/mm/dd").cast("timestamp"),"mm/dd/yyyy"))
df2.show()

+----------+
|     value|
+----------+
|2022/01/08|
+----------+

+----------+----------+
|     value|   newDate|
+----------+----------+
|2022/01/08|01/08/2022|
+----------+----------+
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have date as string in format "yyyy/mm/dd" and you want to convert it to a string with format "M/d/yyyy", then:

- First parse string to Date type using `to_date()`.
- Then, convert Date type to string using `date_format`.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["2022/01/01",],["2022/12/31",]], schema=["date_str_in"])
df = df.withColumn("date_dt", F.to_date("date_str_in", format="yyyy/MM/dd"))
df = df.withColumn("date_str_out", F.date_format("date_dt", format="M/d/yyyy"))

+-----------+----------+------------+
|date_str_in|   date_dt|date_str_out|
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 2022/01/01|2022-01-01|    1/1/2022|
| 2022/12/31|2022-12-31|  12/31/2022|
+-----------+----------+------------+
```